# What is the current accepted view about visiting one's teacher during the festivals?

Tags: yom-tov, travel, rebbe-talmid-muvhak

[Rambam codifies in Hilchos Talmud Torah 5(7)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Torah_Study.5.7?lang=bi&with=About&lang2=en) the mitzvah of visiting one's teacher on the festivals. The Sefaria edition says that the Nodah Biyehudah, Orach Chayim, Vol. II, Responsum 94, notes that this law is not quoted by the Tur or the Shulchan Aruch and does not apply after the destruction of the Temple. It further says that many commentators do not accept that view.

What is the current accepted view about visiting one's teacher during the festivals?

Comment: "accepted view" Accepted by who? Among the people I study and learn with, this is encouraged.

Comment: Also the NBY states: נכון לקבל פני רבו. אף שאין עתה חיוב מכל מקום לא גרע מקימה מפני רבו שאינו רשאי, היינו שאין חוב אבל ראוי  מצד המוסר  - that even though there is no hiyubh it is still the proper and correct thing to do.

Comment: @Deuteronomy Your comment sounds like an answer.

Comment: my first comment is seeking clarification (which hasn't been furnished yet) on what you're actually looking for. My second comment is noting that you've only partially presented the NBY, which can lead to a misleading conclusion.

Comment: @Deuteronomy (1) By "accepted" I meant broadly observed by most mitzvah-observers of whatever stripe. It could be that there is no "accepted" view. (2) I quoted the comments in the Sefaria text of the Mishneh Torah and did not check the actual teshuvah. By your quote of other words in the teshuvah, you significantly contributed towards an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Elyashiv in the sefer הערות על מסכת סוכה asks on this Noda B’Yhedua from the Gemara [Succah 26A](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.26a.3?lang=bi) that states that Amoraim went to visit their teachers on the regel even though it was after the churban.

> כִּי הָא דְּרַב חִסְדָּא וְרַבָּה בַּר רַב הוּנָא כִּי הֲווֹ עָיְילִי בְּשַׁבְּתָא דְרִגְלָא לְבֵי רֵישׁ גָּלוּתָא, הֲווֹ גָּנוּ אַרַקְתָּא דְסוּרָא, אָמְרִי: אֲנַן שְׁלוּחֵי מִצְוָה אֲנַן וּפְטוּרִין.

Rashi explains

> שלוחי מצוה אנן - שבאנו לשמוע הדרשה ולהקביל פני ריש גלותא

R’ Elyashiv answers that although there is no chiyuv there is still a mitzvah to visit your rebbi on the regel.

I believe this is pretty much the accepted view.